# not able to convert JSON string to javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

```
    var JSONObj='[{"rmaNumber":null,"orderReferenceNumber":"referene45","orderStatus":"Pending","dateRequested":null,"dateApproved":null,"segateAddress":null,"billingAddress":null,"shippingAddress":null,"returnForCredit":{"requested":null,"received":null,"shipped":35,"credited":45,"invoiceAmount":null},"returnForExchange":{"requested":null,"received":null,"shipped":35,"credited":45,"invoiceAmount":null},"totals":null}]'
    var parsedJSON = eval('(\'+JSONObj+\')');    
    var result=parsedJSON.result;
    var count=parsedJSON.count;
    alert('result:'+result+' count:'+count);
```

in alert its giving undefined :undefined

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi,I think you are new here, see,If any answer has resolved your problem then you should mark that answer as right, so that can help other people, and this questions will be set as resolved, this is the way how this form works. thanks :)

Comment: @Pratik You're right but the best here would be to close the question as duplicate (I voted to) unless OP explains why he needs to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st thing :**

```
var parsedJSON = eval('(\'+JSONObj+\')');
```

should be

```
var parsedJSON = eval('('+JSONObj+')');
```

**2nd thing :** 
I don't see any `result` or `count` object is json string

**3rd thing :**
data in json is in array, so if any object `result` is there in objects, in array then it should be accessed with `parsedJSON[0].result`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for that:

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSONObj);
console.log(parsedJSON[0].orderStatus);  // "Pending"
```

**Note:** This method is supported by modern browsers only. Read about browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

```
var JSONObj='[{"rmaNumber":null,"orderReferenceNumber":"referene45","orderStatus":"Pending","dateRequested":null,"dateApproved":null,"segateAddress":null,"billingAddress":null,"shippingAddress":null,"returnForCredit":{"requested":null,"received":null,"shipped":35,"credited":45,"invoiceAmount":null},"returnForExchange":{"requested":null,"received":null,"shipped":35,"credited":45,"invoiceAmount":null},"totals":null}]';

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSONObj);    
var result=parsedJSON.result;
var count=parsedJSON.count;
alert('result:'+result+' count:'+count);
```

However you do not have any JSON field called "result" or "count", so those would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead.

for browsers that does not support `JSON.parse` nativly(MSIE) you can use third party libraries like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or [json3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/).

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(JSONObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a quote problem.

You might fix it by replacing

```
var parsedJSON = eval('(\'+JSONObj+\')');
```

with

```
var parsedJSON = eval('('+JSONObj+')');
```

But there is no reason here not to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 0):

```
var parsedJSON = eval(JSONObj);
```

this will give you parsed JSON object already. But there is no property name `result` within your Json object and so do `count`. And if you want to count the array then you just use `length` for e.g `parsedJSON.length`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var JSONObj='[{"rmaNumber":null,"orderReferenceNumber":"referene45","orderStatus":"Pending","dateRequested":null,"dateApproved":null,"segateAddress":null,"billingAddress":null,"shippingAddress":null,"returnForCredit":{"requested":null,"received":null,"shipped":35,"credited":45,"invoiceAmount":null},"returnForExchange":{"requested":null,"received":null,"shipped":35,"credited":45,"invoiceAmount":null},"totals":null}]';

 eval("var  parsedJSON =" + JSONObj);
```